# Ubuntu 16.04: cannot disable or change keyboard shortcuts that conflicts with emacs' for setting mark

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 16.04, emacs

In Ubuntu 16.04, I have disabled the keyboard shortcuts for typing in the Keyboard settings as such:

[image: screenshot]

But this seems to have no effect at all as the keyboard shortcuts remain active.  This is true even after logging out or restarting the computer.  For example, <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> still switches the source of text input instead of setting the mark in emacs:

[image: screenshot]

Notice that the text input source is now Chinese Pinyin.

Instead of disabling the keyboard shortcuts, I have also tried to set them to something else, but this makes no difference at all: Ctrl+Space still switches the text input source.

Comment: Added my answer. Please mention if you manage.

Comment: I have to admit it's odd that change in one place (keyboard settings) doesn't affect the setting in other place too (text entry). Please consider filing a bug report (probably for gnome-settings on ubuntu launchpad).

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> Text Entry

[image: screenshot]

Select the input source whose shortcut you do not want.  For example, Pinyin(Fcitx) is selected here.  Then, click on the button with a picture of a cross formed by a wrench and a screwdriver, and a keyboard.  This opens up the window "Input Method Configuration".  Go to the "Global config" tab:

[image: screenshot]

Here, set the two boxes next to "Trigger Input Method" to "Empty".  This can be done by first left clicking on them and then typing Esc (the escape key).

Comment: Yes it's what I meant, at least the first part. But you can also just change the key-combo on the right side of the first screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the feature, not just it's shortcut.

In Settings > Text field (translated from czech) you can change the shortcut or disable it altogether.

Comment: Please see the answer I posted.  Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 keyboard settings

```
Go to Ubuntu settings
Click on     **Text Entry** 
Click on     **Allow different sources for each window**
Click on     **New windows use the default source**
```

Now the Keyboard settings will return to normal keys for @ and £ characters etc.